# How can I create a raster mosaic using a raster-stack-list based on the max-values of one specific band?

Tags: r, raster

I'm trying to create a (nearly) cloadfree raster stack by comparing the NDVI values (cloads < cloadfree vegetation) of my input rasters from every cell and selecting the "cell-stack" with the highest NDVI ("greenest" thus cloadfree) for the output. My area is about 2500x2500 cells.

The code below is working but will take about 5-10 days for every year (and I'm comparing 20 years).

*snap* is my empty cropped output stack where values ar NA for not in observed area or 0 if they are in observed area.

*merged_raster.list* is a stack.list containing all of my cropped landsat scenes (Band 7 is the NDVI layer)

```
    for (year in dir(landsat_path)){

      for (snap_row in 1:nrow(snap)){
        for (snap_col in 1:ncol(snap)){
          snap_tmp <- snap[[7]][snap_row, snap_col]
          if(!is.na(snap_tmp)){      #TRUE if current cell is in observed area
            best_scene <- 0
            current_scene <- 0
            for (scene in merged_raster.list) {  #comparing every szene to determine the best cell-value
              ndvi_tmp <- scene[[7]][snap_row, snap_col]
              current_scene = current_scene + 1
              if (!is.na(ndvi_tmp)){
                if (ndvi_tmp>snap_tmp){
                  snap_tmp = ndvi_tmp
                  best_scene = current_scene 
                }
              }
            }
            if(best_scene > 0) {
              for (i in 1:7){
              snap[[i]][snap_row, snap_col] <- merged_raster.list[[best_scene]][[i]][snap_row, snap_col]
             }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to increase the efficiency?

Comment: For loops are not so fast in R. Consider using the apply function. Perhaps also refactor your code into smaller functions in order to make it more readable, which will allow for easier code optimization (as it is quite nested now). Otherwise, I'm not really into your problem, but perhaps not all for loops have to loop till the end. Perhaps you could break out of some of them to save time.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
fnames <- list.files(landsat_path)
landsat <- stack(fnames)
nscenes <- length(fnames)

# Initialize vectors of max NDVI and best scene numbers
# These are vectors of zeros with the same number of 
# entries as values in the Landsat scene
max.ndvi <- raster(landsat[[1]])
max.ndvi <- values(max.ndvi)*0 
best.scene <- max.ndvi

for (k in 1:nscenes)
{
  current.ndvi <- values(landsat[[k]])
  higher.ind <- which(current.ndvi > max.ndvi)
  max.ndvi[higher.ind] <- current.ndvi[higher.ind]
  best.scene[higher.ind] <- k
}
```